# Angular JS with jquery masonry

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-masonry

I need to use angular and masonry and also implement sorting and filtering.
The fiddle here does use the masonry with Angular and has filtering and sorting working, however the layout does not seem like masonry. I do not think the masonry layout is applied at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/rdikshit/6swek/3/

```
  <div ng-app="test">
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="nameFilter" />
    <a href="#" ng-click="order = 'id'; reverse=!reverse">Order by id</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="order = 'name';reverse=!reverse">Order by name</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="order = 'age';reverse=!reverse">Order by age</a>
     <div class="items" masonry >
         <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { name: nameFilter } | orderBy: order:reverse" class={{item.style}}>

          <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            <span>id: {{item.id}}</span>
            <br /> <span>Age: {{item.age}}</span>
                         <br /> <span>Style: {{item.style}}</span>

     </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is another fiddle with Passy's directive:
http://jsfiddle.net/rdikshit/6swek/5/

STill does nt work. Even the sorting and filtering are not working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your JSFiddle and got it to [work](http://jsfiddle.net/YnpF7/). Since columnWidth is not specified, the width of the first element is used. That's why there is gap between the elements sometimes

Few points to look out for:

- Don't save the Masonry instance, since you are using the JQuery version. To access Masonry methods, simply get the container element then do `container.masonry( 'methodName', arguments );`
- The watches in the controller are not ideal, in a real app you probably want to put them into a directive
- The technique where you watch the number of children in the Masonry container doesn't work when you have `ngAnimate` as one of your dependency. It cause the DOM tree to be updated after `$digest()`, which make `$watch` miss

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a simular project, but i am using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) with a mansory style.
here is the way i am using it:

**Directive:**

```
    app.directive('isotope', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            items: '=isotope'
        },
        templateUrl: 'social-item.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var options = {
                animationEngine : 'jquery',
                itemSelector: '.social-item',
                layoutMode: 'masonry',
                masonry : {
                    "gutter": 10,
                    "isFitWidth": true
                }
            };

            element.isotope(options);

            scope.$watch('items', function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    element.isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope();
                });
            },true);
        }
    };
});
```

**Directive template (social-item.html):**

```
<div class="social-item" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
    <!--
         Do something with item, in your case something like this:
         <span>{{item.name}}</span>
         <span>id: {{item.id}}</span>
    -->
</div>
```

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div class="social-wall-container" isotope="socials.posts">
    <!-- repeat posts from directive -->
</div>
```

For more information about isotope checkout [This link](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope)
If you decide to use isotope, make sure to include the necesary files located in the [JS](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/tree/master/js) folder on the github page.

Comment: DO you have a fiddle for the above?

Comment: I modified my fiddle a bit and here is the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/rdikshit/6swek/3/

It does not look like a masonary layout at all. ANy help will be appreciated.

Comment: i don't have a fiddle of it.. i never made a fiddle :) but i have it working here on my localhost

Comment: Could you give me the jS and CSS code? to better understand what needs to be supplied for <div class="social-wall-container" isotope="socials.posts"> Also <div class="social-item"

Comment: For the CSS part, just create a simple colored block for testing. the isotope parameter takes your array of items.

Comment: What is isotope="socials.posts"? what values does  this take? COuld you please take a look at the fiddle above to see what I am missing on my CSS

Comment: Your fiddle is way different then my code... socials.posts is an array of items. in your case it would be isotope="items". but you are doing the `ng-reapeat` in your html file where i do it in the directive template.